# How to hide a div is function doesn't exist?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am adding a custom layout for Genesis that will place the blubrry player. I got it correctly but my problem is the wrapping div. It is visible if no Podcast is added.

This is the code for the player:

```
<?php if function_exists('the_powerpress_content') the_powerpress_content(); ?>
```

Here is my complete code:

```
add_action('genesis_entry_header', 'the_powerpress_player');

function the_powerpress_player(){
if(  is_single() || in_category('5') ){
    ?>
    <div class="podcast-div"><?php if function_exists('the_powerpress_content') the_powerpress_content(); ?></div>
    <?php
}
else {

    echo "<div class="no-podcast">";
                echo "<div>";

}
```

}

Is there other way where the div wrapper will show only if if the podcast attachment is added? I tried the above code but I got critical error. With no 'else' clause the div is rendered but I wanted it invisible if no podcast in the post.

TIA

Comment: one is your quotes problem.. and what error do you get ? you can also use style=display:none;

Answer (score 1):

**Replace**

```
echo "<div class="no-podcast">";
```

**With**

```
echo "<div class='no-podcast'>";
      -----------^----------^---
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php function the_powerpress_player(){
          if(  is_single() || in_category('5') ){ ?>
          <div class="podcast-div">
              <?php if function_exists('the_powerpress_content') the_powerpress_content();?>
          </div>
    <?php } else { ?>
         <div class="no-podcast" style="display:none;">
         </div>
    <?php }?>
```